# solve this equation:$A=(2-\sqrt{3})^4+(2+\sqrt{3})^4$

Tags: calculus

Hi please help me solving this puzzle.
Calculate and solve this equstion using relations between roots of quadratic equations.
$$A=(2-\sqrt{3})^4+(2+\sqrt{3})^4$$
Use this relations:
$$ ax^2+bx+c= x^2-Sx+P=0 $$
$$P=\frac{c}{a}$$
$$S=\frac{-b}{a}$$
$$\Delta=b^2-4ac$$
and etc.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use that $$(a-b)^4+(a+b)^4=2(a^4+6a^2b^2+b^4)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2\pm  \sqrt 3$ are roots of $$ x^2-4x+1$$
With p=1 and $s=4$

Thus $$x_1^4 +x_2^4=(s^2-2p)^2-2p^2$$

$$=(16-2)^2-2=194$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$A_n=(2-\sqrt3)^n+(2+\sqrt3)^n.$$
Then
\begin{align}
A_{n+1}-4A_n&=(2-\sqrt3)^{n+1}-4(2-\sqrt3)^n+(2+\sqrt3)^{n+1}-4(2+\sqrt3)^n\\
&=(2-\sqrt3-4)(2-\sqrt3)^n+(2+\sqrt3-4)(2+\sqrt3)^n\\
&=-(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)^n-(2-\sqrt3)(2+\sqrt3)^n\\
&=-(2-\sqrt3)^{n-1}-(2+\sqrt3)^{n-1}=-A_{n-1}.
\end{align}
We get the recurrence
$$A_{n+1}=4A_n-A_{n-1}.$$
With this, we can find $A=A_4$ without messing around with $\sqrt3$s.

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ and $v$ are the solutions of $x^2-4x+1=0$, we have to compute
$$\begin{align}
u^4+v^4&=(u+v)^4-4u^3v-6u^2v^2-4uv^3\\
&=
(u+v)^4-4uv(u^2+v^2)-6u^2v^2.
\end{align}.$$
Now use $uv=1$, $u+v=-4$ and $u^2+v^2=(-4)^2-2\cdot 1=14$.